# How to refresh page after force download in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

[image: This is my page]

```html
 public function index()

    {
     $this->load->helper('download');
  $this->load->model('public/news_events_model', 'news_events_model');

  if(isset($_POST['download']))
  {
   $fname = $this->input->post('fname');
   $lname = $this->input->post('lname');
   $company = $this->input->post('company');
   $wemail = $this->input->post('wemail');
   $telephone = $this->input->post('telephone');
   $country = $this->input->post('country');
   $ip=$this->input->ip_address();

   $array = array('rfname' => $fname,
         'rlname'=>$lname,
         'rcompany'=>$company,
         'rcemail'=>$wemail,
         'rip'=>$ip,
         'rtelephone'=>$telephone,
         'rcountry'=>$country);

   if($this->input->post('download') == "Download")
    {
     $this->news_events_model->commonInsert('get_report_details',$array);
     force_download('public/report/HVAC DESIGN.pdf', NULL);
     
    }
   redirect($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'refresh'); 
  }

  $this->data['news_events'] = $this->news_events_model->get_news_events();


  $this->load->view('public/includes/header', $this->data);

  $this->load->view('public/includes/header_sub', $this->data);

        $this->load->view('public/news_events_view', $this->data);

  $this->load->view('public/includes/training_centre_view', $this->data);

  $this->load->view('public/includes/our_clients_view', $this->data);

        $this->load->view('public/includes/testimonials_view', $this->data);

  $this->load->view('public/includes/location_map_view', $this->data);

  $this->load->view('public/includes/footer', $this->data);
 }
```

I'm doing a form in codeigniter. After the user fills the form and click submit button, data is inserted into database and well as a pdf file (company profile) is download. I'm using force_download to download the pdf file. When the form is submitted , data is getting entered into database as well as pdf is getting downloaded. But the page doesnt refresh. Can someone tell me how to refresh page after force_download?

Comment: you can refresh page using redirect($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'refresh');

Comment: its not working...

Comment: Can you show your force download code

Comment: i have added the code in my question

Comment: If your form submit method is post , you cant refresh as it will show security error

Comment: @hs-dev2MR can you explain bit more please

Comment: Why do you need to refresh !!!

Comment: You can't redirect the client after a download on the same request. When you force download a file, all headers and output must only be about the file download. If you add any additional redirect headers or extra output, it will mess up your downloaded file.

Comment: What you can do: When a user submits the form, use Ajax to save the data and return an ID. Then, in your ajax callback, open a new window (in js) to a URL just for the download and pass in the id. On that page, use the ID to get the user data and generate the PDF and force download it. Then, in the js that opens the window, you can redirect the user after the window is opened.

Answer (score 0):

**Do like below:**

```
$this->load->helper('url');

$currentURL = current_url();
redirect($currentURL);
```